# Why is MATLAB giving me an error that states that "index in position 2 is invalid"?

Tags: matlab

This code seems like it should be simple, but for some reason I keep getting this error: "Index in position 2 is invalid. Array indices must be positive integers or
logical values."

It refers to these lines:

```
Vr = (V*R)/(sqrt((R^2)+(w*L-(1/(w*C))^2)));
VR(1,i) = Vr;
```

I've tried checking if I entered the equation wrong or if I have to save certain values as integers but nothing seems to work. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the full code if you need:

```
disp('Please enter Vo in volts, R in kiloOhms, L in miliHenries, and C in picoFarads');
input = input('Enter values as single matrix.  ');

V = input(1,1);
R = input(1,2);
L = input(1,3);
C = input(1,4);

VR = zeros(1,1000);      

for i = 0:1000
    w=i*10*10^-9;
    Vr = (V*R)/(sqrt((R^2)+(w*L-(1/(w*C))^2)));
    VR(1,i) = Vr;
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: because you are indexting `VR(1,0)` right in the first call of the look. And `0` is not a valid index

Answer (score 1):

Your `for loop` starts from zero but `Matlab` is 1-indexed language.

```
VR = zeros(1,1000);      

for i = 1:1000 % <- Mistake was here, change zero to one
    w=i*10*10^-9;
    Vr = (V*R)/(sqrt((R^2)+(w*L-(1/(w*C))^2)));
    VR(1,i) = Vr;
end
```